# How to display selected spinner item name from first activity and associated string from second activity both on the second activity?

Tags: java, android, xml

When a spinner item is selected in the first activity, I want the selected item’s name to appear at the top of the screen of the second activity (which it does) and also display the string associated with the selected item in the second activity (which it currently does not).

Currently it displays the same string regardless of which spinner item is selected.

I think I am supposed to call the string resource from the second Java class, but I’m not sure how to do it. I have looked for answers here and elsewhere, but nothing has worked so far. I would really appreciate if someone could show me how this is done. Thank you!

If I click on anything the "battleship" string displays. How do I get it to display only when battleship north carolina is selected? Strings have to be stored in the string resource file. Thank you I am new to android. This is my first project.

Here is Java code and activity for first activity:

```
 

    private boolean isFirstSpinnerItem = true;
    
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
    
            findViewById(R.id.sites);
            String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            if (isFirstSpinnerItem) {
                isFirstSpinnerItem = false;
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, text);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
    
        }
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sites"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:entries="@array/historic_sites" />
    
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is Java code and activity for second activity:

```
 

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String messageText = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            TextView messageView = findViewById(R.id.sites);
            messageView.setText(messageText);
        }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sites"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:entries="@array/historic_sites"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/battleship"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/battleship"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

```
 <resources>
        <string name="app_name">Wilmington Walkabout</string>
    
    
        <string-array name="historic_sites">
            <item>Please select an option</item>
            <item>Battleship North Carolina</item>
            <item>Wilmington Railroad Museum</item>
            <item>Bellamy Mansion Museum</item>
        </string-array>
    
        <string name="battleship"> display only if battleship north carolina is selected.</string>
    
        <string name="railroad"> display only if Wilmington Railroad Museum is selected</string>
        
        <string name="house">display only if Bellamy Mansion Museum is selected</string>
    
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to choose which value display in TextView i suggest send by Intent only position and then in DetailActivity display values using this position

You can do it like that:

```
sitesArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.historic_sites);

((messageView.setText(sitesArray[position]);

battleshipArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.battleships);
    
((battleshipView.setText(battleshipArray[position]);
```

[EDIT] create array in resources like this

```
  <string-array name="battleships">
            <item>display only if battleship north carolina is selected.</item>
            <item>display only if Wilmington Railroad Museum is selected.</item>
            <item>display only if Bellamy Mansion Museum is selected.</item>
 
        </string-array>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but this didn't work for me.

Comment: you created second array in resources? What exactly not work?

Comment: I should say, I could not implement using an array (I'm still learning programming fundamentals), I used strings and called them from DetailActivity. Thank you again, kind sir.